# Interpreting specific compiler warnings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, compiler-warnings

I'm receiving three warnings for the code below. The warnings are:

> 1: "Receiver type 'const char *' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'"
>   2: "Instance method '-alloc' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"
>   3: "Instance method '-hideBanner:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    MoPubManager *obj = [["MoPubManager.h" alloc] init];

    if( obj.adView ) {
        [self hideBanner:YES];
    }
    [obj.adView refreshAd];

}
```

What do these mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a cstring instead of the class. Try this:

```
MoPubManager *obj = [[MoPubManager alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. However, the warning "Instance method '-hideBanner:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')" is still there, highlighting `[self hideBanner:YES];`

Comment: It means that you have not implemented the hideBanner:(BOOL) method (or you have a declaration of the method after the point you do the call, without a declaration in the header file)

Comment: Cool thanks. I imported the header file that the method is found in, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: If this method is from another class, then you shouldn't call it on self but instead on an object instantiated from that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, instead of `[self hideBanner:YES];` should I do `[obj.adView hideBanner:YES];`

Answer (score 2):

`"MoPubManager.h"` is the name of a header file, not the class that it represents.  You probably want to use `[[MoPubManager alloc] init]`.

Comment: `MoPubManager.h` is the name of a header file, `MoPubManager.a` would be the name of a library file.

Comment: @jonmorgan Thanks a lot, that fixed it! However, the warning "Instance method '-hideBanner:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')" is still there, highlighting `[self hideBanner:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

```
MoPubManager *obj = [["MoPubManager.h" alloc] init];
```

Surely you meant:

```
MoPubManager *obj = [[MoPubManager alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
MoPubManager *obj = [[MoPubManager alloc] init];
```

`"MoPubManager.h"` is the header file, not the class name